# css grid-column-gap creates inconsistent gap size

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to render a single row of divs with an equal 1px gap between them, but this is proving harder than I thought.

I'm trying to accomplish this with either css-grid or flexbox.

with CSS-grid I tried the following:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;

  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  column-gap: 1px;
`
```

Which resulted in this:

[image: chart result]

(all of the divs inside should be equal size and have a 1px gap inbetween them).

However as you can tell, there is a gap missing between several of the divs...

If I increase the gap size to 2px it becomes apparent that it's a space issue.

[image: space issue]

Now you can see that some columns have a gap of 2px and some have a gap of 1px (likely because there isn't "room" for all of them to have exactly 1 or 2px gap inbetween and still keep the divs an equal size.

And as expected if I resize the overall container these are in, the amount and location of the missing gaps change. This confirms it's a problem with the available space.

However what I want to happen in this case is to have priority on the gaps rather than the divs being the same size. I would prefer if one (or multiple if requires) of the divs inside are 1px less wide than a missing gap as that would be much less noticeable.

Resizing the main container to match a scenario where it fits perfectly is not an option as it's a responsive design.

I also tried to use flexbox gap instead but it results in the same CSS issue with inconsistent gaps:

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;

  display: flex;
  gap: 1px;
`

const Item = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
`
```

How do I force the gaps to always be the same size, but compromise on the size of the divs to make sure the gaps are always exactly 1px wide?

Comment: Try to set the width of the divs to auto instead of hard coding a size. Also, try to remove `flex: 1` from items.

Comment: @Arcanus oh that's interesting. If I set width to auto in the flexbox example and leave flex: 1 there it seems to work! (it didn't work for the css-grid though) but that's good enough for me. Thanks! You can put an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with gaps and width.

First, it's important to understand the problem. When you set width to 100%, you are telling the div to take up a certain amount of space, in this case 100%.

A better approach would be to give the div/element a height you want, but set the width to auto, which is more dynamic and won't encroach on the gaps you're trying to set.

```css
.my-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  display: 'flex';
  gap: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```js
const note = document.querySelector('.main');
note.style.display = 'flex';
note.style.gap = '1px';
note.style.flexWrap = 'wrap';
```

```css
.main>div {
  flex: 1 0 25px;
  background-color: green;
  /*25 px is minimum width of content check flex-basis*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>a</div>
</div>
```